# Rails invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 when using htmlentities gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, nokogiri, html-entities

So I have the controller who scrapes the entire html of a page and stores it into mysql database. Before I store the data I want to encode it using the htmlentities gem. My issue is that with some websites it works ok e.g `https://www.lookagain.co.uk/` but with others I get `invalid byte sequence in UTF-8` such as `https://www.google.co.uk/` and I do not know why. At first I though it might be something wrong with the database so I have changed all the fields to LONGTEXT but the problem still persists

Controller:

```
class PageScraperController < ApplicationController
    require 'nokogiri'
    require 'open-uri'
    require 'diffy'
    require 'htmlentities'

    def scrape

        @url = watched_link_params[:url].to_s
        puts "LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOG#{@url}"
        @page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(@url))
        coder = HTMLEntities.new
        @encodedHTML = coder.encode(@page)
        create

     end

     def index      
        @savedHTML = ScrapedPage.all
      end

      def show
        @savedHTML = ScrapedPage.find(id)

      end

      def new
        @savedHTML = ScrapedPage.new


      end

      def create

        @savedHTML = ScrapedPage.create(domain: @url, html: @encodedHTML, css: '', javascript: '')

        if @savedHTML.save

          puts "ADDED TO THE DATABASE"

          redirect_to(root_path)
        else

          puts "FAILED TO ADD TO THE DATABASE"

        end
      end

      def edit

      end

      def upadate

      end

      def delete
        @watched_links = ScrapedPage.find(params[:id])
      end

      def destroy
        @watched_links = ScrapedPage.find(params[:id])
        @watched_links.destroy
        redirect_to(root_path)
      end

    def watched_link_params

        params.require(:default).permit(:url)

    end

end
```

Comment: Try encoding the response instead of the Nokogiri doc. It not clear why you'd want to do that in the first place though.

Comment: Ins't it better to encode the html before saving it to the database ?

Comment: No, you definitely don't want to do that.